# Can Passpoint be disabled in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, hotspot

Is there a way to disable or prevent Android from trying to connect to a Passpoint (Hotspot 2.0) access point in API 28 and lower? Looking through the [WifiManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager), I don't see anything for disabling it or preventing it from scanning for it.

Comment: Hi! Do you have any updates on this issue? I can't seem to find a solution via adb neither

Comment: Unfortunately the fix had to be done at the OS level through a vendor I work with. Doesn't appear to be something available in the API